# How to set overlay on the page using laracast flash in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, overlay, flash-message

I've already tried :

```
Flash::overlay('message');
```

But no result.

Answer (score 3):

Controller action would be something like..

```
   //use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   public function flashTest(Request $request){
   //see explanation for following line at very end
    $request->session()->forget('flash_notification'); 

    //Flash::success('this is an alert message'); //if you want to show alert message

    Flash::overlay('Modal Message'); 
    return view('yourview');
   }
```

in view

```
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap css-->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--if it's not an overlay, show flash message-->
 @if (!Session::has('flash_notification.overlay'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        {{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}
    </div>
 @else

 <!--perform your overlay action here. For now i am showing a model-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>

    <!-- bootstrap Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{ Session::get('flash_notification.title') }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  @endif
  <!-- other code -->

  <!-- bootstrap js -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

OR

if you exclusively want to use this package only;
run command `php artisan vendor:publish`
after adding code in config/app.php as stated in [laracast/flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash).

This will add two package views in the "/vendor/laracasts/flash/src/views/" directory. Here you will find the default views (you can customize them).

now in your view file simply add

```
<body>

 @include('flash::message')<!-- this line is important -->

 <!-- bootstrap js -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- This is only necessary if you do Flash::overlay('...') -->
 <script>
$('#flash-overlay-modal').modal();
 </script>
</body>
```

Explanation for  `$request->session()->forget('flash_notification');`

Somehow this package was retaining keys of overlay session variable. i.e. if you show overlay message first and next time you want to show flash message, a flash message would also appear as an overlay. This line is added to prevent this behavior. refer  [laravel session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session) .

Also check out this [bootstrap overlay](http://karbonn.github.io/Overlay-Bootstrap/)

Comment: Ty for your answer but i want an   'overlay' . With the code provided ,Only flash alert is shown.

Comment: I have tested above code and its working fine. Show us your code; how you are doing it and  also mention if there are any errors messages.